# Ninject with MVC3 RTM

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I've upgraded MVC3 from RC2 to RTM. We were using Ninject 2.1.0.76, but things stopped working once I upgraded. So I used the NuGet manager to get the latest Ninject, Ninject.MVC3 and Ninject.Web.Mvc libraries (2.1.0.91, 1.0.0.0 and 2.1.0.39 respectively). Now, it creates an AppStart_NinjectMVC3 file.

I removed NinjectHttpApplication from my global.asax and made it back into a regular HttpApplication. When I tried to build, I get;

"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Looking further, if I disable the following line;

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel));

The build goes through. But I'm pretty sure I don't want to do this.

Any ideas?

----- UPDATE ---------

I created a new MVC3 project, added the reference to Ninject.MVC3 and this builds and runs fine. I compared web.config, don't see any differences that relate to Ninject or MVC in the two. A fresh project doesn't add the Ninject.Web.Mvc library, so I removed it and commented out all code relating to that, and still, the error occurs.

Comment: Do you get a runtime or a compile-time error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta the `IServiceLocator` interface [is replaced](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html) by [`IDependencyResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver%28VS.98%29.aspx). I'm not sure Ninject.MVC3 already has a release where they have implemented this interface.

Judging from the line `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel))` it appears they have not.

[Here's](http://brainafk.com/aspnet-mvc-3-beta-idependencyresolver-ninject) a simple implementation of this interface for Ninject.

**UPDATE**: The `Ninject.Web.Mvc` library has a [`NinjectDependencyResolver`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/NinjectDependencyResolver.cs) class that extends from the `IDependencyResolver` interface. I think you should use this one (I do and everything works fine).

Comment: If I look at the object browser for the ServiceLocator, the base type shows as IDependencyResolver. I tried swapping out the locator with the sample implementation, but get the same issue.

Comment: I've changed this out, but I'm still getting the issue. So this is looking like a configuration problem. The sample project I started had 2.1.0.76 of Ninject, no Ninject.Web.Mvc and Ninject.MVC3 1.0.0.0. This builds fine. All projects in my solution have 2.1.0.91, and I've tried swapping back out but no luck.

Comment: You may want to check that the Ninject libraries have a dependency on the correct MVC library (version 3 RTM) and not on an older version.

Comment: So, I checked Ninject.MVC3, dependency on 2.1.0.76. So, I removed .91, removed ninject.web.mvc .39 (because that was built against .91), added in Ninject.76 and ninject.web.mvc .20. I now lose the NinjectDependancyResolver (seems that was added in .39) and I'm back to the same issue.

Comment: As Remo Gloor suggests, I don't think you need the `Ninject.MVC3` library. I have never used it, although the name suggests you need it. Just use `Ninject.Web.Mvc`, use the `NinjectDependencyResolver` class that's in there and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Download the dlls from here

https://github.com/ninject/ninject/archives/master

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/archives/master

Further more do not use Ninject.MVC3 all you need ist Ninject.Web.Mvc

I also have an article documenting same [here](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/11/13/official-ninject-mvc-extension-gets-support-for-mvc3)